# missing operator or semicolon error message

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tadoquery

hi ive got an SQL with the following code,

> SELECT SUM (Travel_Cost)
>   FROM Travel
>   WHERE Job_ID=:mcode

in order to allow the user to enter a value from an edit component which is passed to the SQL i have got the following code aswell,

```
procedure TfrmExpenses.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);      
begin          
  ADOQuery1.active:=false;      
  ADOQuery1.Parameters('mcode').AsString:=Edit1.Text;      
  ADOQuery1.active:=true;      
end;
```

I keep on getting the error message

> "missing operator or semicolon"

when i try to compile, any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a specific line where you get that? This code looks okay, but maybe you got some more. The compiler should tell you the exact line.

Comment: The `Parameters` property is of type `TParameters` and not 'indexed'. Hence, you cannot 'pass' a string to it as an 'index' or 'parameter'. I have never worked with database controls, so I have no idea what this is actually about, but from a syntax point of view, for instance, `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamValues['mcode'] := 'Test';` and `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('mcode').Value := 'text';` compiles.

Comment: Cont with what Andreas posted, try using ParamByName instead of Parameters.  Also, make sure that the parameter input type 'mcode' matches the Job_ID field type.. if both are integers, set the parameter input type to integer, and convert the edit1.text to integer during your assignment.

Comment: yeh It fixed when i changed the line
    `ADOQuery1.Parameters('mcode').AsString:=Edit1.Text;`
to `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('mcode').Value:=Edit1.Text;`
thanks

Comment: i'm afraid it did for me, not sure why.

Comment: @David: I tried the code, and it does in fact give the 'missing operator or semicolon' error at `Parameters` in Delphi 2009.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Mea culpa. Clearly I got hung up on the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

While the `TParameters` class does have a default property, it accepts an `Integer`, not a `string`.

If you know the index of the parameter you can use:

```
var I: Integer;
....
ADOQuery1.Parameters[I].AsString := Edit1.Text;
```

Otherwise you need to use:

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('mcode').AsString := Edit1.Text;
```

Note: You'll want to avoid using any of the `*ByName` functions (`ParamByName`, `FieldByName`, etc) in a tight loop if you can because each call performs a linear search on the underlying collection until it finds a match. Not really relevant in this particular case but worth taking into consideration.